# How to put your Laravel application in maintenance mode and still allow a certain user?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Somewhere in my `app/start/global.php` I have

```
App::down(function()
{
    return Response::make("Be right back!", 503);
});
```

If I did

`php artisan down` in my cmd my whole site will disable.

I am afraid that I will disables all the visitors `including` admins.

I don't want that. I still want to allow myself in there because I have to create/upload some contents onto my site.

Is there a way to allow the access to my self and other admin users, but not the clients ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store your ip address and other admins ip address in the white listed array of ip addresses, something like this:

```
App::down(function()
{
    $ip = Request::getClientIp();
    $allowed = array('192.168.1.7', '192.168.1.8', '127.0.0.1');

    if(!in_array($ip, $allowed))
    {
        return Response::view('maintenance', array(), 503);
    }
});
```

OR

Perform an if else check base on user type

```
if ( Auth::user()->type == "Admin"){

..... Allow


}else{

..... NOT Allow

}
```